# Как сделать, чтобы записанное значение обнулялось при смене value?

Tags: javascript, change

Есть калькулятор, который после расчета выводит значение в

```
<font id="itog">0.00</font>
```

при помощи:

```
document.getElementById("itog").innerHTML = X;
```

В калькуляторе есть кнопки:

```
<div class="form_radio_btn" id="k-1668008100191" data-section-id="1668008100191">
<input data-el-id="1668008023355" name="k-1668008023355" type="radio" id="radio_1668008023355_1" value="1"><label for="radio_1668008023355_1"><span>Значение 1</span></label>
<input data-el-id="1668008023355" name="k-1668008023355" type="radio" id="radio_1668008023355_2" value="2"><label for="radio_1668008023355_2"><span>Значение 2</span></label>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при смене Value (то есть при переключении кнопки) значение в id="itog" сбрасывалось на 0?

При этом Value приведено всего 2 для примера - в самом калькуляторе их больше 50.

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно зачем ты используешь тег `font`...

> Тег `<font>` представляет собой контейнер для изменения характеристик шрифта, таких как размер, цвет и гарнитура. Хотя этот тег до сих пор поддерживается всеми браузерами, он **считается устаревшим** и от его использования **рекомендуется отказаться** в пользу стилей.

http://htmlbook.ru/html/font

Так же не понятно зачем "сбрасывать в 0"...

Привожу пример того как можно менять значение в элементе с ИД `itog`.

```js
document.querySelector('.form_radio_btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const o = e.target
  if (o.tagName != 'INPUT') return
  // вот так сбрасывать в 0
  //document.querySelector('#itog').textContent = 0
  document.querySelector('#itog').textContent = o.value
})
```

```html
<div class="form_radio_btn" id="k-1668008100191" data-section-id="1668008100191">
  <input data-el-id="1668008023355" name="k-1668008023355" type="radio" id="radio_1668008023355_1" value="1"><label for="radio_1668008023355_1"><span>Значение 1</span></label>
  <input data-el-id="1668008023355" name="k-1668008023355" type="radio" id="radio_1668008023355_2" value="2"><label for="radio_1668008023355_2"><span>Значение 2</span></label>
</div>
<font id="itog">0.00</font>
```